# How to create hashmap which will hold 528 bit record in binary

Tags: java, hashmap, bitset

I need to create a hash map which will hold 528 bit binary data. How would the binary data be stored in the hashmap?

Example: 0000000001000000100000000... this is 25 bits.  Similarly, I need to store 528 bits.

Do I need to convert this value into some byte array, or can I directly store the data in memory?

An example would be of great help.

Comment: Do you want the values of your Hashmap being such 528-bit blocks?

Comment: yes . can i do that or do i need to convert it into byte array before storing? Will Bitset class be of any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not complicate your life.

Assuming `value` is of `String` type, then if you:

#### Store `key` as `String`

Probably easiest and most readable.

```
    String value = "some data", key = "0101101010101010101011010110101010010101";
    HashMap<String, String> map = new java.util.HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put(key, value);
```

**Additional:**
To convert a key of type `byte[]` to `String`, you can use `BigInteger` class, for example:

```
    byte[] keyb = { 90, -86, -83, 106, -107 };
    String keys = new BigInteger(keyb).toString(2);
```

Element `keys` will have a value: `101101010101010101011010110101010010101`.

#### Store `key` as `byte[]`

Personally I would like to avoid this. Simple default hash function in this case hashes the reference to the array as key, but we want deep hash (all elements must be equal). Following will not work as described:

```
    HashMap<byte[], String> map = new HashMap<byte[], String>();
    map.put(new BigInteger(key1, 2).toByteArray(), value);
```

One way to `fix` this, is to put the array in the class or extend collection called `ArrayList` and rewrite the equals and hash method. It is not as trivial as it seems - you really need to know what you are doing.

#### Store `key` as `BitSet`

Extracting, adding or manipulating bits is not most efficient - it's even rather slow. So this seems only good option if it impacts the memory size very noticeably and that's a problem.

```
    String value = "some data", key = "0101101010101010101011010110101010010101";
    HashMap<BitSet, String> map = new HashMap<BitSet, String>();
    map.put(getBitSet(key), value);
```

You can create a makeshift `BitSet` class converter like:

```
public static int keySize = 41;
public static BitSet getBitSet(String key) {
    char[] cs = new StringBuilder(key).reverse().toString().toCharArray();
    BitSet result = new BitSet(keySize);
    int m = Math.min(keySize, cs.length);

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        if (cs[i] == '1') result.set(i);

    return result;
}
public static String getBitSet(BitSet key) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int m = Math.min(keySize, key.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
        sb.append(key.get(i) ? '1' : '0');

    return sb.reverse().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Do i need to convert this value into some Byte array ?

A byte array is one option.  Others include arrays of short, int or long, or (possibly) instances of the `Bitset` class.  Which one is best depends on how the "record" objects are created and how your application processes them.

Once you've decided on the representation type,creating a hash table with the record as values is simple; e.g.

```
HashMap<SomeKey, Record> map = new HashMap<SomeKey, Record>();
map.put(someKey, record); 
...
```

> or directly I can store the data in memory?

You can't do that in Java.

Comment: How to do this with Byte array? I want to do it with Bitset class.

Comment: @JavaBits: You can simply use `HashMap<SomeKey, Bitset>` as your type, and store these bitsets into your map. I don't really see your problem here.

Comment: @JavaBits - I don't see your problem either.